# Why create method's parameter showing error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
def create  
    @player = Player.create(player_params)
end
```

Why player_params is showing "undefined local variable or method `player_params' for #" ?

**form:**

```
<%= form_for(@player) do |f|%>
<div class="field">
        <%= f.label :player_name%><br>
        <%=f.text_field :player_name%>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <%=f.label :price%><br>
    <%=f.text_field :price%>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :team_id%>
    <%= f.select(:team_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Team.all,     :id, :team_name),{prompt: 'please choose'}, class: "form-control")%>
</div>

<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Where you have defined `player_params` ?

Comment: I think I have got conceptual problem regarding that. Can you please tell me what to do or suggest me where to define?

Comment: you should have a method named `player_params` (i.e. a method block starting with `def player_params` in that file, or a file that defines a class which this one inherits from.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just missed the `player_params` part

Here it is a sample one: (It depend on your model)

```
def player_params
  params.require(:player).permit(:name, :desc)
end
```

More information:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Comment: OFF: Thanks for the reformating, just got into this UI :)

Answer (score 2):

you should define a method of player_params and then permit the variables that are required.

Comment: It kinda does answer the question, actually.